# How to remove parameters from AMS 0.10.0.rc4 Deserialization?

Tags: active-model-serializers

Given the following user_params:

```
  def user_params
    ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(params.to_unsafe_h)
  end
```

I am unable to remove a parameter in order to do a specific operation that requires the `:current_password` to be removed. Previously the line below did the job:

```
user_params.delete(:current_password)
```

However, since implementing 0.10.0.rc4, the operation in question generates ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'current_password' for User.)

```
user.update_without_password(user_params)
```

I am unsure if this is a bug or a syntax mistake, so I decided to post on SO instead of their Github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update #1

As requested by BF4, I created [issue #1610](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1610) on AMS Github regarding this question. In the meantime, the original post below is a workaround while a final fix is created.

#### Original Post

I could not find a way to remove the params, but using `.except(a)` does the trick like in the Update method below:

```
  # Render the updated User using UserSerializer and the AMS Deserialization.
  def update
    # Check if password is blank, if so, clear :current_password
    # and update without password, else updates password.
    if user_params[:password].blank? || user_params[:current_password].blank?
      user.update_without_password(user_params.except(:current_password,:password))
      render json: user
    else
      if user.update_with_password(user_params)
        render json: user, status: :ok
      else
        render json: user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing this question and answer in the https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers repository?